# declaring string in if statement and using it outside of it C#

Tags: c#, string, if-statement

I've been coding a text adventure game, and one of the random scenarios is where you can meet a pokémon and fight it. There are some options (like looking at inventory) that require you go back to the menu (fight, run, items, poké). For example, if you input a wrong command then you're supposed to go back to the menu. However, in the method, the only parameter is `hasEncountered`, and when the random scenario is triggered then it's false by default (bool), meaning

```
        if (hasEncountered == false)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("While travelling you go through a patch of tall grass..");
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            Console.WriteLine("*pokemon music*");
            Thread.Sleep(1500);
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("You encounter a {0}!", pokemon1);
        }
```

is triggered. Whenever a user inputs a wrong command, the method is recalled. I don't want the user to see this part again, so I did this:

```
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine(" < {0} >", pokemon1);
        }
```

However, the string "pokemon1" in the `if statement` is undeclared, although I declared it in the beginning of the method.

```
    public void ConScen3(bool hasEncountered)
    {
        string pokemon1;
        TextAdventure1.ConjoinedScenarios.ConjoinedScenario conScen = new TextAdventure1.ConjoinedScenarios.ConjoinedScenario();
        if (hasEncountered == false)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("While travelling you go through a patch of tall grass..");
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            Console.WriteLine("*pokemon music*");
            Thread.Sleep(1500);
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("You encounter a {0}!", pokemon1);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine(" < {0} >", pokemon1);
        }
```

If I try to declare `pokemon1` in the `if` statement, it says it's already declared. However, if I remove the `pokemon1` string in the beginning, the rest of the code complains that it's undeclared. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: It's not complaining that it's undeclared, it's complaining that it has no value assigned.

Answer (score 1):

You do *declare* the variable (that's what `string pokemon1;` does), but you don't *assign* a value to it.

You have to give the variable a value, like `pokemon1 = "Foo";`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign a value to pokemon1:

```
public void ConScen3(bool hasEncountered)
    {
        string pokemon1 = "pikachu";
        TextAdventure1.ConjoinedScenarios.ConjoinedScenario conScen = new TextAdventure1.ConjoinedScenarios.ConjoinedScenario();
        if (hasEncountered == false)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("While travelling you go through a patch of tall grass..");
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            Console.WriteLine("*pokemon music*");
            Thread.Sleep(1500);
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("You encounter a {0}!", pokemon1);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine(" < {0} >", pokemon1);
        }
    }
```